# PHP/AJAX posts limit per page

Tags: php, xml, ajax

so I started developing a blog for myself, and I came to the first setback.
I want  to replace the posts that this function returns with ajax with the next 10. I know javascript quite well but I don't know so much about ajax (all I know that it sends a request to the server where the results are posted back, and then you can replace the data with the new data on your site)

```
function get_posts($i = 0,$max = 10) {
global $con;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for (;$i < $rows&&$i < $max;$i++) {
    $row_res=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    printf("<h1>%s</h1><p class='user'>Posted By: %s</p>
            <p class='date'>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>", 
            $row_res["title"],$row_res["user"],$row_res["date"],$row_res["content"]);
}
}
```

this returns well. I made links that execute an AJAX function that should return the next ten. this is the function:

```
function func1() {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","connect.php?func=1",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}
The connect.php?func=1 points to an if that executes the get_posts() function with new args. but it doesn't show anything or it shows the first post at the top of the page and another first post in the content section.

Comment: ohh and you can see it on my website [link](http://tristann.tk)

Comment: Definitely look into JQuery to do this for you. Look up "JQuery load"

Comment: It's very unclear what your problem is. When I look at your site the first page shows some entries and when I click '2' there are no entries. Is that the failure you are trying to solve?

Comment: yep, that is the issue. But as case1352 suggested I will look into that and try to solve my issue. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Okay, It works now, I had some syntax errors and wasn't passing the variables good. Now I have another issue. when I press the button and want to load the results from 10-20 I still get the first results. I think it has something to do with mysqli_fetch_array(). how can I make that it get's posts that eg. in row 5 or higher?